# jQuery: Highlight div box onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onload, highlight

This jQuery code will highlight the div box when clicked.

I want to get the highlight **on load**, how can I do that?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
div { margin: 0px; width: 100px; height: 80px; background: #666; border: 1px solid black; position: relative; }
</style>

  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

$("#div1").click(function () {
      $(this).effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
});

  });
  </script>
</head>
<body">
  <div id="div1"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the statement for `highlight` in document.ready at the same level you are binding `click` event..

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZUV7C/)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#div1").effect("highlight", {}, 3000); //this will highlight on load
      $("#div1").click(function () {
           $(this).effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
      });    
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, this way might be a little cleaner in that if you add some other effects that you want to show on the click state, you only need to define them one time.

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
      $("#div1").click(function () {
           $(this).effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
      });    
      $('#div1').click();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#div1").effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
});
```

This will highlight the `div1` when the document is ready. If you also want a `click` handler, you can keep it and put in whatever code you want (ie. you can also keep the `effect` in there as well, if you want to).

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bizmark/h2aDy/)